# When is a minimal immersion holomorphic?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, complex-geometry, harmonic-analysis

Let $(X,g_X)$ be a Riemann surface and $(Y,g_Y)$ a Kahler manifold. Let:

$\phi\colon X\to Y$

be a minimal immersion, that is, a conformal harmonic smooth map with respect to $g_X$ and $g_Y$. If I am not mistaken, every holomorphic immersion from a Riemann surface to a Kahler manifold is a minimal immersion. I am interested in the opposite question: I would like to know the weaker set of sufficient conditions currently available in the literature (such that compactness, curvature conditions etc) on $(X,g_X)$ or $(Y,g_Y)$ that guarantees that such minimal immersion is holomorphic. The literature on these beautiful topics is huge, so it is not so easy to dive in and cleanly extract a number of clear necessary conditions for the case I am interested in.

Thanks.

Comment: I know that you are interested in the other direction, but a holomorphic map from a Riemann surface to a Kähler manifold need not be an immersion.  Maybe you meant to say that a holomorphic *immersion* from a Riemann surface to a Kähler manifold is a minimal immersion.  Also, maybe you want a 'weaker set of *sufficient* conditions.... that guaranteee that a minimal immersion be holomorphic'.

Comment: @RobertBryant Indeed you are right, my bad! Thanks!

Comment: @RobertBryant About the necessity of assuming holomorphic immersion, that is what I thought first, but then I read page 8 of http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/37004/1/WRAP_THESIS_Arezzo_1996.pdf which claims that every holomorphic map from a Riemann surface to a Kahler manifold is a minimal immersion. Perhaps in this particular case the "immersion" condition follows from holomorphicity?

Comment: That claim is simply false, though; there are plenty of holomorphic maps from Riemann surfaces to Kähler manifolds that are not immersions.  The author of the source you are reading was perhaps being careless.  A correct statement is this:  A non-constant holomorphic mapping from a connected Riemann surface to a Kähler manifold is an immersion outside of a discrete set of points in the domain.

Comment: Let me answer another question or rather give instances where a harmonic map between two Kähler manifolds is automatically holomorphic. If a map from a closed Kähler manifold to a complex hyperbolic manifold is harmonic and has real rank >2 at a point it is holomorphic (due to Carlson and Toledo). Here complex hyperbolic manifold = quotient of complex hyperbolic space. There is a similar statement due to Siu, changing complex hyperbolic space by another hermitian symmetric space of noncompact type (but "2" has to be replaced by a bigger constant then).

Comment: I agree that this is not really an answer, as in what I describe the domain has to be high-dimensional...

Comment: In some situations if the minimal surface is stable, then it is holomorphic. This paper summarize some cases in its introduction:

http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASNSP_2000_4_29_2_473_0

However, stability does not always implies that the map is holomorphic, as shown in

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870804001021?via%3Dihub